# Finding maxima in a vector using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

i'm trying to find [local maxima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) of a vector of numbers using MATLAB. The built-in [findpeaks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) function will work for a vector such as:

```
[0 1 2 3 2 1 1 2 3 2 1 0]
```

where the peaks (each of the `3`'s) only occupy one position in the vector, but if I have a vector like:

```
[0 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3 2 1 0]
```

the first 'peak' occupies two positions in the vector and the `findpeaks` function won't pick it up.

Is there a nice way to write a maxima-finding function which will detect these sort of peaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [REGIONALMAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imregionalmax.html) function from the Image Processing Toolbox:

```
>> x = [0 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3 2 1 0]
x =
     0     1     2     3     3     2     1     1     2     3     2     1     0

>> idx = imregionalmax(x)
idx =
     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: this is what i ended up using thanks. followed by shrinking the result with bwmorph to get one result for each peak.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [ 0 1 2 3 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 ];

sizeA = length(a);

result = max(a);

for i=1:sizeA, 

    if a(i) == result(1)
       result(length(result) + 1) = i;
    end
end
```

`result` contains the max, followed by all the values locations that are equal to max.

Answer (score -1):

Something much easier:

```
a = [1 2 4 5 5 3 2];
b = find(a == max(a(:)));
```

output:

```
b = [4,5]
```